# How to monitor an incoming sms in android 4.2

Tags: android

I want to use intent-filter, but I cann't find `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` in android 4.2 or greater.

I mean I can not get code hints in the adt  when i choose compile with android 4.2.
But when i compile with 4.1 ,that's ok. I can get the code hints,and when the sms is coming ,i will know.

What should I do to monitor an SMS in android 4.2? Is there any way I can be notified when I receive a message?

```
<receiver android:name="com.itheima.mobilesafe.receiver.SmsReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }
 }
```

Comment: you have mentioned receiver in correct way... please share your receiver  source code ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: As of Android M you need to get the runtime permissions and the below code won't run as it is until runtime permission is requested

```
 public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
                SmsMessage smsMessage;
                if (intentExtras != null) {
                    Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
                    if (null != sms) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                                smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i], intent.getStringExtra("format"));
                            } else {
                                smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);
                            }
                            if (null != smsMessage) {
                                String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                                String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                                //your logic here
                                } else {
                                    //handle null case;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

And in your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

            <receiver
                android:name=".SMSReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```